Как работают Asset Bundles в Unity?
Не совсем понятен их смысл. Везде пишут, что они могут загружаться динамически по мере надобности, отсюда прирост производительности и экономия памяти. Но каким образом, если ассеты лежат в проекте, т.е загрузка происходит в любом случае? Как это все работает?

Ну как минимум из «ассеты лежат в проекте» никак не следует «загрузка происходит в любом случае»

Вот я и спрашиваю, чтобы объяснили механизм

Asset Bundles не лежат в проекте. Они одним из способов собираются из ассетов лежащих в проекте в архив. Потом этот архив можно разместить на сервере и скачать его.
Unity далеко не все ассеты собирает в билд. Гарантированно окажется в билде всё в папках Resources и Assets/Streaming Assets, но обычные ассеты окажутся там только в том случае, если на них есть ссылка из этих ассетов, из одной из сцен в Build Settings (теперь Build Profiles) или из Project Settings/Player/Optimization/Preloaded Assets. Соответственно, нужно следить за тем, чтобы не было дублирования ассетов. И тогда и содержимого Asset Bundles в билде не будет.
